# Trimming white space on left side of string without using any built-in functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to remove all whitespace on the left side of the string, whitespace is considered \n \t and " ".

I want to try using raw code excluding built-in functions.

```
  let removeWhiteSpace = function(str) {
  let newString = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] != " " && str[i] != "\t" && str[i] != "\n") {
      newString += str[i];
    }
  }
  return newString;
};
```

Comment: Why no methods? School?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function removes all whitespace, not just whitespace on the left.

You need to break out of the loop when you reach the first non-whitespace character, and then return the rest of the string.

```js
let removeWhiteSpace = function(str) {
  let newString = "";
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] != " " && str[i] != "\t" && str[i] != "\n") {
      break;
    }
  }
  for (; i < str.length; i++) {
    newString += str[i];
  }
  return newString;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(removeWhiteSpace("   This is a string  ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet is close, but you'll want to stop removing whitespace once you reach the first non-whitespace.

You should also initialize your variables, otherwise, newString will start off as `undefined`. Appending a char to `undefined` will cast `undefined` to a string first, resulting in e.g. `'undefined0'`.

Lastly, use `!==` (and `===`) in stead of `!=` (and `==`) to avoid conversion errors.

```js
let removeWhiteSpace = function(str) {
  let newString = '';
  let foundNonWhitespace = false;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] !== ' ' && str[i] !== '\t' && str[i] !== '\n')
      foundNonWhitespace = true;
    if (foundNonWhitespace)
      newString += str[i];
  }
  return newString;
};

console.log(removeWhiteSpace('   yo  there'));
```